# Android everytime I add an ID to a view I have to make a clean install

Tags: android, eclipse

Everytime I add an ID to a view or create a new view with an ID I have to make a clean install, i.e uninstall manually the app on devices then reinstall through Eclipse. If I don't, nothing works properly, some views doesn't show up or others bugs like that.

Anyone has any idea about what's causing this issue ?

(when I remove the id and then recompile, everything is back, but I can't add ids)

**EDIT** My error: I was missing the default values with sharedpreferences, I don't understant what is wrong

**EDIT** I found out what was my mistake: I was storing IDs of views in settings in sharedpreferences (to know what the user selected) and use those IDs to conststruct views according to what the user had chosen. But when we add a new ID Eclipse regenerate R.java with new IDs for **ALL** views to keep them in order (according to the order they appears in layouts) in ascendent order and the smallest possible

If I have R.java like:

```
public static final int first_id=0x7f020021;
public static final int second_id=0x7f020022;
public static final int third_id=0x7f020023;
```

and I if I add a view between the second and the third view and add an ID to this view, R.java is regenerated and it goes like:

```
public static final int first_id=0x7f020021;
public static final int second_id=0x7f020022;
public static final int fourth_id=0x7f020023;
public static final int third_id=0x7f020024;
```

Comment: Hmm, can you check if you have `build automatically`, in projects I think, checked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try cleaning your project?

Comment: Can you explain in little more in depth whats going wrong and what you did/do to solve the problem?

Comment: I have a ScrollView with text views inside, I read a SQLite database to construct those textviews. When I add a new view to my app and an id to it (for the layout of that activity or another activity), then, the database is not read, (sometimes the asynctask to read it throw an exception, but I can't reproduce that to show you the exception) 
And the settings that I store in sharedpreferences are messed up

To solve this I manually uninstall the app on device and then run it again through Eclipse and it's ok

Comment: Oh ok so whatever you do to mess up, you save in the Shared Preference which then messes up the app.. That's crazy dude. Could you copy and paste your code? I know you cant do the error but maybe your eclipse code?

Comment: It's a long code so I will post the essential. With some toast I manage to find where where was the bug, and indeed it's with sharedpreferences, I'm adding this + thanks, you saved my app